# How to include hibernate connection string in application.properties into .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have been trying gitlab ci/cd for a spring-boot app that uses hibernate. But unfortunately my gitlab ci/cd build phase gets failed. I need to know how the hibernate connection string which is included in application.properties file to be included in .gitlab-ci.yml

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://my_ip:3306/db_test?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username= db_user
spring.datasource.password= password
```

And this is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - package
  - deploy

build:
  image: java:8
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./mvnw package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/unecast-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  only:
    - development

package:
  stage: package
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/username/application .
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/username/application
  only:
    - development

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk upgrade && apk update
    - apk add openssh-client
    - apk add sshpass
    - sshpass -p "$STAGING_SERVER_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGING_SERVER_USER@$STAGING_SERVER docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
    - sshpass -p "$STAGING_SERVER_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGING_SERVER_USER@$STAGING_SERVER docker pull registry.gitlab.com/username/application
    - sshpass -p "$STAGING_SERVER_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGING_SERVER_USER@$STAGING_SERVER "docker container stop unecast_dev_api && docker container rm unecast_dev_api || true"
    - sshpass -p "$STAGING_SERVER_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGING_SERVER_USER@$STAGING_SERVER docker run --name unecast_dev_api -p 8080:8080 -d registry.gitlab.com/username/application
  only:
    - development
```

I want to know how the values in application.properties could be included in .gitlab-ci.yml in order to connect my database.

Answer (score 0):

You need not add application properties to gitlab yml. if you really want, define like this in your gitlab yml (not suggested)

```
variables:
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: user1
```

Also , in your build step use mvn docker image rather than java docker image. Make sure to use correct version which your application supports.

Follow the blog here https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/14/continuous-delivery-of-a-spring-boot-application-with-gitlab-ci-and-kubernetes/

Error Screenshot would help if you are still not able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Gitlab, you can store your sensible value in secret variable.

As [documented](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/), there are two types of variables supported by GitLab:

- `Variable` : the Runner will create an environment variable named same as the variable key and set its value to the variable value.
- `File` : the Runner will write the variable value to a temporary file and set the path to this file as the value of an environment variable named same as the variable key.

In your case, I suggest to use `File` type. In gitlab, go to your project > Settings > CI/CD > Variables and copy the content of your `application.properties` in a variable. In my example, application_properties (Gitlab doesn't support `.` in variable key name) :

[image]

In your job, you can find the path to this file in the value of the `application_properties` environment variable.